# need to route two domain mail servers using MX record

Tags: dns, smtp, sendmail, mx-record

I have two domains in GoDaddy(default one mail account only - not hosted any where)

> 1. example1.com
> 2. example2.com

My requirement is to set MX record in example1.com, to send mail to these two domains.
Depending on domain name I need to send to my SMTP in example1.com.

Please give me exact flow what I need to follow, I am new to this MX records stuff.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "requirement ... example1.com to send mail to these two domains"

add two MX records with identical priority to example1 zone

> "depending on domain name I need to send to my SMTP in example1.com"

add one MX record, which specifies example1 mail server, to those other domains.

Comment: Can you please explain briefly...

My crireria
1. example1.com   -  having SMTP details(username and password) with one email ID (a@example1.com)
2. example2.com   -  having SMTP details(username and password) with one email ID(b@example2.com)


I send mail request to exmaple1.com, with example1.com smtp details and from mail ID b@example2.com.
Then my mail need to route to example2.com SMTP, and then it will sent from SMTP.

Comment: MX records don't deal with usernames or passwords. They deal with host- and domain names.

Comment: means based on domain name, it will automatically route to from address domain name... Am I right ??

Comment: Translating to what I understood you said: "based on (recipient) domain name, mail will be sent to one, or another, or both mail servers". If that's what you asked, then "yes"

Comment: Can you please give me some tutorials on A, MX and PTR records...
Because I am new to this field....

Comment: I prefer to refer you to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types - each record type has a link explaining it in much more detail than I could possibly put into the limited comment space here.